# cUrl : Argument list too long

Tags: curl, json

I'm getting the error: `Argument list too long` when trying to use cUrl to send a file in base64 inside the body of my JSON.

I'm using something like this:

```
DATA=$( base64 "$FILE" )

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
   "data": "'"$DATA"'"
}' $HOST
```

Is there any other way to get the DATA in the body of my JSON?

Take into account that I need to read a file in my filesystem, transform it into base64 and then send it inside the body.

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003855/curl-and-posting-base64-data-to-a-php-uploading-script

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the base64-encoded file is too big to fit in the argument list you are going to have to pass it via a file. One of the easier ways I can think of is to pass it via standard input. From the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d), you can use `-d @-` to read from stdin instead of the command line.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$HOST" <<CURL_DATA
{ "data": "$DATA" }
CURL_DATA
```

Comment: You can also use this version I like it more:
`echo { "data": "$DATA" } | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$HOST"`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/), without having to store the base64-encoded file in a shell variable:

```bsh
jo data=%"$FILE" |
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- "$HOST"
```

This creates a JSON document  with a `data` key.  The value for that key will be the base64-encoded contents of the file referenced by the `$FILE` value.

It's the `%` after `=` in the argument that makes `jo` base64-encode the file.  Had you used `@` instead, the file would have been included as a JSON-encoded string.