# Curl - Argument list too long

Tags: curl

My Question is similar to [cUrl : Argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174350/curl-argument-list-too-long)

I am sending the following command to CURL from unix shell script

```
var=$(base64 sample.pdf | perl -pe 's/\n//g')
var1=$(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index5/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "'"data"'" : "'"$var"'" }')
echo $var1
```

I got error as `curl: /usr/bin/curl: cannot execute [Argument list too long]`

Can anyone help to rewrite the above CURL code, to read the 'base64' content from a separate file instead as the argument limit is long ?

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved.

I tried as below,It worked..

```
var1=$(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index5/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d @test.json)
echo $var1
```

Comment: what's in test.json

Answer (score 1):

On systems with `/dev/fd/x`, you can also do:

```
var1=$(
  curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index5/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d @/dev/fd/3 3<< EOF
 { "data" : "$(base64 sample.pdf | tr -d '\n')" }
EOF
)
```

Depending on the shell implementation, the data is stored in a temporary file or fed via a pipe.

With `zsh` or `bash`, you can also do:

```
var1=$(
  curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index5/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' \
    -d @<(
      printf ' { "data": "'
      base64 sample.pdf | tr -d '\n'
      printf ' }\n'
    )
)
```

Which would be slightly more efficient and also work for commands that output binary data.