# Curl argument list too long error in elastic search mapping and setting

Tags: bash, curl, elasticsearch

```
mapping=(</index_automation/{product}/mapping/Mapping/"$tempmappingfile")

settings=(</index_automation/{product}/mapping/Mapping/"$tempsettingsfile")

dataraw="{{mapping},{settings}}"

creds=$(</index_automation/obj/creds.txt)

reindexfile="/index_automation/${product}/mapping/Mapping/reindex.txt"

IFS=", " read -r -a credArr <<< "$creds"

result=(curl --silent -u {credArr[0]}:{credArr[1]} -X PUT "{credArr[2]}/${indexname}/"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--data-raw "$dataraw")
```

In the above codebase I am reading the mapping and settings for a new index creation. For `--data-raw "$dataraw"` I am getting

```
curl: argument list too long
```

error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why don't you create a file with the data and include it with `--data @filename` as described in the manual?

Comment: @Kusalananda Can you please share me manual details? or any example

Comment: use `-d@ -` as mentionned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174350/curl-argument-list-too-long?rq=1 for `$dataraw` part.